# How to autowire beans inside the implementation of a NoRepositoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Using Spring Boot / Spring Data, I added a custom functionnality to all my repositories. This is a snipped of what I did :

So I have my repository Interface :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface RepositoryBase<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
```

And its implementation

```
public class RepositoryBaseImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements RepositoryBase<T, ID> {

    @Autowired 
    MessageLocale messageLocale; // <- this is a classic spring bean which is not injected in this spot (always null)

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public RepositoryBaseImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    //... My custom methods here
```

and my config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.base.pkg", repositoryBaseClass = RepositoryBaseImpl.class)
public class RepositoryConfig {
}
```

My custom methods works correctly but I need to inject messageLocal

Autowired don't work inside RepositoryBaseImpl (I think that is because it is not a bean)

I cannot add @Repository on RepositoryBaseImpl because I use @NoRepositoryBean on its parent interface

So is there a way to inject messageLocale ?

Comment: Check this post.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345287/how-to-inject-a-dependency-into-a-repository-base-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345287/how-to-inject-a-dependency-into-a-repository-base-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Prabhakar D comment, I will post my answer based on my need (using @EnableJpaRepositories besides @EnableMongoRepositories and some other little modifications)

In the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation, add the repositoryFactoryBeanClass :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.base.pkg", repositoryBaseClass = RepositoryBaseImpl.class, repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MyRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
```

**The key thing that is you can use @Autowire inside a repositoryFactoryBeanClass**

Create a repositoryFactoryBeanClass and autowire your beans in it. This is a spring bean that create a custom JpaRepositoryFactory in the overrided method createRepositoryFactory :

```
public class MyRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends JpaRepository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private MessageLocale messageLocale;

    public MyRepositoryFactoryBean(Class repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new MyJpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager, messageLocale);
    }
}
```

Now, create the custom factory (MyJpaRepositoryFactory) and use the overrided method getTargetRepository to create an instance of your base repository (RepositoryBaseImpl). Here you can inject your bean in its constructor :

```
public class MyJpaRepositoryFactory extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    private MessageLocale messageLocale;

    public MyJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager, MessageLocale messageLocale) {
        super(entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.messageLocale = messageLocale;
    }

    //****************** Edit ********************
    //starting from spring boot 2.1.0, getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information) was made final. So you can't override it anymore. You will need to override getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information, EntityManager entityManager)
    //@Override
    //protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information) {
    //    return new RepositoryBaseImpl(getEntityInformation(information.getDomainType()), entityManager, messageLocale);
    //}
    @Override
    protected JpaRepositoryImplementation<?, ?> getTargetRepository(RepositoryInformation information, EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new RepositoryBaseImpl(getEntityInformation(information.getDomainType()), entityManager, messageLocale);
    }
    //****************** End Edit ******************** 
}
```

Now, just modify the constructer of your RepositoryBaseImpl so it can accept the required Bean :

```
public class RepositoryBaseImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements RepositoryBase<T, ID> {

    private MessageLocale messageLocale;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    //if you are using IntelliJ, it can show you an error saying "Could not autowire. No beans of JpaEntityInformation". It is just a bug in IntelliJ
    public RepositoryBaseImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager, MessageLocale messageLocale) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.messageLocale = messageLocale;
    }

    //... My custom methods here
```

Now that your messageLocal is injected in your BaseRepositoryImpl, you can use it in your custom methods without having to pass it in parameters

Hope that this will help someone